# Freebase MQL query - Get data by a social link

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm having a hard time trying to get data about a person from Freebase using his social link - by a MQL query.

How could this be done?

Something like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={
     "*":[{}],
     "/common/topic/social_media_presence":[{
          "value":"http://twitter.com/JustinBieber"
     }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links are really stored as keys and the links are generated from templates with they key plugged in.  You can see all the keys here: https://www.freebase.com/m/06w2sn5?keys=

A modified version of your query would be:

```
[{
  "key": [{
    "namespace": {
      "id": "/authority/twitter"
    },
    "value": "JustinBieber"
  }],
  "*": [{}]
}]
```

You can do the same thing with other namespaces like /authority/facebook or /authority/musicbrainz as well as the various language wikipedias e.g. /wikipedia/en

I'm not sure how complete the coverage or currency of the social media info is though...